# Should I create repository items outside the repository interface?

Tags: c#, entity, repository-pattern, dto

A coworker is using the convention of "Entities and Dtos" to implement the Repository pattern in our application. This was his idea and I am not familiar with the idioms.

Currently, the main differences between Entities and Dtos are:

- Entities have an ID field (Dtos have too, I find it smelly);
- Dtos have a `Clone` method;
- Entity properties have a more serialization-friendly datatype, and the conversion is performed by data-mappers;

The question is:

> Should I be creating my Dtos freely at the client side, and *then* send them to the repo? Or should I ask for new Dto instances *only* at the repo interface?

This would be the difference between:

```
TDto dto = new TDto();
// edit dto properties
repo.Add(dto)
```

and

```
TDto dto = repo.Add(); // repo : Repository<TDto>
// edit dto properties
repo.Update(dto);
```

Is there a preferrable way? If it's a matter of preference and I prefer the second option, should I take care not to paint myself into some corner?

(Disclaimer: frankly, I think this Entity/Dto is overkill for our relatively simple client desktop application, which only has trivial serialization-based CRUD needs, but I am willing to follow the "pattern" as long as it solves problems instead of getting in the way)

UPDATE:

One problem I am currently facing and trying to solve is the "Smelly Id Property". Currently, Id is set in the Dto when it is added. The code is like this:

```
    public Patient Add(Patient patient)
    {
        patient.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        var entity = patient.ToEntity();
        _patientsCache.Add(entity);
        this.Salvar();
        return patient;
    }
```

Notice that the method call returns the same Dto, only now with its Id set to value created by the repo. My mind looks at this and thinks "this is not right", but I cannot justify it convincingly.

Comment: It would be unusual to call `Add()` and not expect it to actually add anything to the underlying store.  Maybe `new()` or `create()` but the repository should not be responsible for creating instances of your classes, IMO.

Comment: @stephen.vakil thanks for your interest. I have updated the question with a snipped of the actual code. The Id field - who creates it, and when - is what bothers me most.

Comment: OK, so the pattern you have updated with is perfectly reasonable to me if I am making correct assumptions.  If you want to hide the existence of Entity Framework from your layers outside of the repository, it would be reasonable to have the repo layer take in a dto that gets mapped to an entity.  When you are doing an add, you often will want the id back if it gets generated by the DB, because you may want to take further action with the `patient`

Comment: @stephen.vakil Thanks again! Actually, there is no DB and no Framework, my coworker just created two POCOs that are almost the same except for the difference enumerated in the question. And I own all the code, so I can change it if there is a better design. What I _really_ want to encapsulate is the very existence of an "ID" field, since it has no use to the client application, only to the repo. As such, I wonder where this ID should come from if I instantiate the dto client-side. Perhaps as a readonly property initialized upon Dto construction?

Comment: If the sole purpose is truly for the repo to have an identifier, then you shouldn't be setting id when you create new instances yourself.  The id would be passed around because when you do an update or other operations, the repo would need to be able to locate the record easily.  So if you load out of the repo, do some stuff client side, then save, the repo needs to know which record to save.  Of course, an alternate approach would be to uniquely identify your `patient` using fields within the patient.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, there is no "right" answer when it comes to the complexity and architectural decisions.  As you pointed out, if the application is small, it might be excessive to engineer too many layers into it.  On the other hand, it's harder to refactor later if the application grows in size.

As for the question of where to instantiate the DTOs; it's only instantiation.  If you're calling the default constructor and your constructor is behaving in a non-smelly way -- i.e. it's not performing complex logic or doing things that have side effects, but rather is only setting up a default or "empty" instance of your DTO -- then it really doesn't matter where you do it.

I'd say do it on the client side because it's simpler and saves you one round-trip.

If you don't want your client to know about the "ID" field in your DTO, then make it an `internal` field or property, and set it in the repository code.

Comment: Nice! One problem though: since Dtos have an ID field, so that the repo can know what entity instance to update, where and when do you think it is sensible to create that Id? Currently, Dto constructor does not set Id - this is set by the `repo.Add(TDto dto)` method. But TDto then has a public Id property! Do you have a suggestion for that?

Comment: Hold on, I'm checking [Fowler](http://www.martinfowler.com/books/eaa.html) (good book, by the way)....

Comment: I updated my question with the actual code, which by the way is a mix of the two signatures in my example. I find it quite smelly, but don't know what smell it is...

Comment: I couldn't find anything definitive, but my best guess is that you want to obtain the new ID somehow from the repository in a prior step and then pass it with your DTO to the repo create method.  Sorry, that's the best I could come up with at this point.

Comment: If you truly want to encapsulate, then just apply the new ID to the DTO instance inside the repo create method.  The ID could be private or internal, so only the repo code could access it.